# How to allow gem install from github source on digitalocean server

Tags: github, rubygems, bundler, ruby-on-rails-5

Hello thank you for reading!

how do i open up and allow github gem source to be run on digitalocean server.

> Retrying `git clone 'git://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower.git'
>   "/home/DIR/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/cache/bundler/git/acts_as_follower-325dbadb5c64b190d66abe4d3ec636f4d3716066"
>   --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` due to error (2/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone
>   'git://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower.git'
>   "/home/DIR/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/cache/bundler/git/acts_as_follower-325dbadb5c64b190d66abe4d3ec636f4d3716066"
>   --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /Dir has failed.fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0:IP]: errno=Connection
>   refused github.com[1:IP]: errno=Connection refused

Any help on this would be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solution added down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the global.

> git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/